# Replicating a wrong analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, reproducible-research, replicability

A study measures the performance of patients and controls in two tasks.

In task 1, a t-test reveals no significant differences between patients and controls. In task 2, a t-test reveals significant differences between patients and controls.

The study concludes that the difference in performance across groups depends on the task.

Following, for example, this paper

> Nieuwenhuis, S., Forstmann, B. U., & Wagenmakers, E. J. (2011). Erroneous analyses of interactions in neuroscience: a problem of significance. Nature neuroscience, 14(9), 1105.

my understanding is that to make the above conclusion performing two t-tests is not correct and instead one should, for example, look at the significance of the interaction term of an ANOVA.

If I perform a replication study of the original study and found:

- the same significances for the t tests
- no significant interaction in the ANOVA

What should I conclude about the success of the replication of the original study?

Comment: Potentially relevant: Gelman and Stern (2006), ["The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not
Itself Statistically Significant"](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf).